# How to make a minimal request in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket, request

I'm trying to send one byte to my server, but with headers all my requests contain at least around 500 bytes;
Ajax, jQuery, Fetch - All of them add a big bunch of headers and there is no way to remove them.

Of course, a request is the wrong way to do this. Only I have no experience with sockets in JS and PHP. How do I send minimal bytes with JS and receive them with PHP?

Comment: How does the byte know where it has to go?

Comment: Agreed the one byte restriction is arbitrary and unnecessary and in any case impossible. I can understand you may want to keep traffic to a minimum but a few bytes here or there won't make any difference. Just send the smallest message you can manage

Comment: My favorite thing would be `sendByte("example.com", "1", callBack)` so that there is just a domain given as the address, or an IP.

Comment: I need an to know it as fast as possible when a specific event occurs on the server, so I use a short interval. But that's problematic if you use mobile data...

Comment: Maybe what you really want is [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events)

Comment: I didn't know that was even possible! Thank you Felix :)

Comment: Should I just delete this question now?

Comment: *"I didn't know that was even possible!"* A great example for why it's important to ask about the *problem* you are trying to solve and not your attempted solution. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Just a note about what you want to do and `php`. Depending on where you host your application it can be problematic to get that working. Most hosters only provide PHP behind a web server like apache or nginx. And you only have a certain amount of PHP processes available. Each connection for a SSE (like long polling) will occupy a PHP process until the connection is closed again, in that case, and depending on the number of users you might run out of available porcesses really fast. Some hosters allow you to run a PHP background process that can be used to set up a WebSocket server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Every packet of every protocol uses more than 1 byte. No matter if it's TCP, UDP or something else. After all, they have to know where to go.

So there is no way to send only one byte over the internet.

Comment: Your user name is very fitting for this question :D